# Writing a git revision hash (SHA-1) to a PostgreSQL database with psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, git, psycopg2, sha1

##### Short

What's the most efficient and effective way to store a git revision hash (SHA-1) such as `f844cdc09651448d6c3e765fadac448253a16928` into a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) database (> v.11) with [`psycopg2`](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/)?

##### Details and code

I have an SHA-1 hash as an hexadecimal string in Python, which I would like to store in a PostgreSQL database:

```py
import psycopg2
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

psycopg2.__version__ # prints '2.9.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)'

cmd_list = [ "git", "rev-parse", "HEAD", ]
process = Popen(cmd_list, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
git_sha1 = stdout.decode('ascii').strip()

conn = psycopg.connect(**DB_PARAMETERS)
curs = conn.cursor()
sql = """UPDATE table SET git_sha1 = %(git_sha1)s WHERE id=1;"""

curs.execute(
    sql,
    vars = {
        "git_sha1": git_sha1
    }
)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

For the moment I have a `git_sha1` field in the database as `VARCHAR(40)`, but as a git [revision hash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) is an [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) string, it can be better to restrict the characters to only be [0-9a-f]. But I don't feel comfortable to manually set a domain only for that field... I have the feeling it should exist a better and more robust way for doing that.

So, does such a better and more elegant way exist for writing this kind of data in a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) database?

Versioning:

- Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00)
- git version 2.33.1
- psql (PostgreSQL) 12.4 (Ubuntu 12.4-1.pgdg18.04+1)
- Ubuntu 18.04 (5.4.0-87-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Comment: A SHA-1 hash is a 160-bit unsigned integer (or more fundamentally, just 160 bits with no other semantics). A 40-character hexadecimal string is just one representation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git IDs are [SHA-1 checksums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1). These are represented as 40 character hex strings, but they are really 20 byte numbers. Store them as binary data: `bytea`. This will cut storage in half.

[`decode`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-binarystring.html#FUNCTIONS-BINARYSTRING-OTHER) the hex string when inserting, [`encode`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-binarystring.html#FUNCTIONS-BINARYSTRING-OTHER) back to hex when fetching.

```
create temporary table foo ( git_id bytea );

insert into foo (git_id) values 
  (
    decode('f844cdc09651448d6c3e765fadac448253a16928', 'hex')
  );

select encode(git_id, 'hex') from foo;
```

In psycop2, or you can convert it to [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) and psycop will do the right thing.

```
curs.execute(
    sql,
    vars = {
        "git_sha1": bytes.fromhex(git_sha1)
    }
)
```

See [Binary adaptation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html?highlight=bytea#adapt-binary) in the psycop docs.

Comment: Note that Git is switching to SHA-256 (eventually). This should not affect this answer though.